# JBoss Fuse - get body type

Tags: java, jboss, apache-camel, blueprint

I'm new to JBoss Fuse platform and I'm trying to run a simple Apache Camel XML route to send email messages. Incoming messages may be of specified type T, but also there can be an XML, which I then need to unmarshal using JAXb to get an object of type T. So I need a filter to check if incoming message type is not T then unmarshal it. How can I accomplish that? I need something like:

```
<filter>
  <simple>${body.type} != 'T'</simple>
  <unmarshal ref="jaxB" />
</filter>
```

Comment: Found a walkaround with xpath filter: `<xpath>/a/b</xpath>`. So if there is such XML node body will be unmarshaled. Any better ideas would be useful..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
<filter>
  <simple>${body} not is 'your.class.Type'</simple>
  <unmarshal ref="jaxB" />
  <to ... />
</filter>
```

or

```
<filter>
  <simple>${body} is 'java.lang.String'</simple>
  <unmarshal ref="jaxB" />
  <to ... />
</filter>
```